# Why does CUDA 8.0 (sometimes) have a bad memory access, while 7.5 doesn't?

Tags: c++, cuda

I was upgrading to CUDA 8.0 when some of the code started giving different results. I managed to locate roughly replicate the issue with a MCVE and solve my issue.

```
#include <cub/cub.cuh> // Tested with cub 1.5.5

#include <stdio.h>

static inline void f(cudaError_t err, const char *file, int line)
{
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        fprintf(stderr, "ERROR in file %s, line %d: %s (%d)\n", file, line, cudaGetErrorString(err), err);
        fprintf(stdout, "ERROR in file %s, line %d: %s (%d)\n", file, line, cudaGetErrorString(err), err);
    }
}

#define CHKERR(expr) do {f(expr, __FILE__, __LINE__);} while(0)

template<int dimSize>
__device__ __inline__ void UsedToWork(double *s_arr)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    typedef cub::BlockReduce<double, dimSize> BlockReduce;
    __shared__ typename BlockReduce::TempStorage temp_storage;

    // This following line was the issue
    double r = BlockReduce(temp_storage).Sum(s_arr[idx], dimSize);
    __syncthreads();
    if (idx == 0)
        printf("t0 here %f\n\n", r);
}

template<int size>
__global__ void ShouldWork(double *input)
{
    int idx = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;

    __shared__ double s_arr[size];
    if (idx < size)
        s_arr[idx] = input[idx];
    __syncthreads();

    UsedToWork<size>(s_arr);
}

int main()
{
    const int arraySize = 32;
    double h[arraySize] = { 
         1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10,
        11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20,
        21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30,
        31, 32
    };

    double *d = 0;
    cudaError_t cudaStatus;

    CHKERR(cudaMalloc((void**)&d, arraySize * sizeof(double)));
    CHKERR(cudaMemcpy(d, h, arraySize * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    ShouldWork<32><<<1, arraySize * 2 >>>(d);

    CHKERR(cudaGetLastError());
    CHKERR(cudaDeviceSynchronize());
    CHKERR(cudaFree(d));

    return 0;
}
```

I replaced the line of interest with

```
double r = BlockReduce(temp_storage).Sum((idx < dimSize ? s_arr[idx] : 0.), dimSize);
```

ensuring that if `idx` was greater than `dimSize` (the size of the array) it wouldn't accessed (`an illegal memory access was encountered (77)`). While this was obviously an error, why did CUDA 7.5 allow the memory access without issue in the first place? Just to make things more interesting, if in the kernel I replace the

```
UsedToWork<size>(s_arr);
```

call with its (should be inlined anyway) definition

```
typedef cub::BlockReduce<double, size> BlockReduce;
__shared__ typename BlockReduce::TempStorage temp_storage;
double r = BlockReduce(temp_storage).Sum(s_arr[idx], size);
__syncthreads();
```

CUDA 8.0 doesn't give me the `an illegal memory access was encountered (77)` error. Now I'm just confused. Shouldn't the behavior at least be consistent?

Compiled on Windows 7, VS2013. Run on a Titan with 369.30.

Comment: @talonmies Can you be more specific in pointing out my copy-pasta?

Comment: nvm, found it. Sorry.

Comment: I get out of bounds memory detected with CUDA 7.5 and CUDA 8.0

Comment: Can I ask about your setup? I didn't get it on Ubuntu 14.04 with a 980 either (7.5)...

Comment: Linux 64 bit, gcc 4.8.4, maxwell GPU

Comment: And I believe you should always get an error. You have a block size of 64 threads and a shared memory buffer of 32 elements. That will always fail

Comment: I know it *should* always fail. That's really the gist of my question. I just copy/pasted the example to Ubuntu 14.04 64 bit, gcc 4.9.3, using a Maxwell card (980, driver 352.93). Compiled with `nvcc test.cu -I./ -o t -arch=sm_52`. It still ran without error. I can't test the CUDA 8 there due to driver incompatibility. Weird.

Comment: The only real difference is the driver. I can't help you explain a problem I can't reproduce.

Comment: Did you run your code with cuda-memcheck on the passing CUDA 7.5 case?

Comment: An out-of-array-bounds access doesn't necessarily trigger an error. It only does so if the out-of-bounds access is to memory not owned by the process (on the CPU) or not belonging to the current device context (on the GPU). The varying details of memory allocation can thus expose or hide such out-of-bounds accesses in unpredictable fashion, which is why tools like `valgrind` exist to find the otherwise silent cases of out-of-bounds access.

Comment: @njuffa if you want to provide an answer I would upvote.  Otherwise I'm going to provide a CW answer at some point.  As far as I am concerned, the answer to this is clear.  Out of bounds indexes don't necessarily cause a runtime detectable fault.  This is true for both host and device code.  You can use a tool like `cuda-memcheck` (device code) or `valgrind` (host code) to force any OoB index to fault.  Beyond that, you are at the mercy of compiler, CUDA version and actual GPU device, for the determination of memory layout and other relevant characteristics.

Comment: @RobertCrovella Go ahead with a CW answer, I have to catch a movie now :-) Isn't there a functional difference between `valgrind` and `cuda-memcheck`? As I understand ,`valgrind` tracks all allocations and instruments code to check all accesses against bounds of those allocations: it never misses any OOB access, may produce *false positives*, though. Flip-side is that apps may run extremely slow with `valgrind`. I don't think `cuda-memcheck` has the capability of checking every memory access against the bounds of each allocation and may miss OOB accesses that land within a different allocation

Comment: That's possibly true.  But without (valgrind/cuda-memcheck) there are many more possible access patterns that land on nothing at all (no definition) that still won't be captured via runtime error checking mechanisms.  The tightest you can get in either case is (AFAIK) valgrind/cuda-memcheck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The GPU has a runtime memory checker the details of which are unpublished.  This memory checking facility is not perfectly precise, but if an egregious enough error occurs (out-of-bounds access by a sufficient margin, say) then the runtime memory checking will flag a fault, halt the kernel, and declare that the context is corrupted.

The specific conditions which this will occur in are unpublished, and may vary from GPU architecture to GPU architecture, and also from CUDA version to CUDA version, as well as other possible factors.

As was conjectured in the comments, a possible mechanism for runtime error checking could be if the GPU code touches memory not associated with its context.  A given array out-of-bounds index then may have a dependency on where that array happens to be located in the context memory map, to determine if a particular out-of-bounds extent will actually go outside the context.

Such a memory map is quite possibly variable from CUDA version to CUDA verison, GPU architecture to architecture, and even probably depending on specific compile switches.

For best (strictest) memory access validity checking, its recommended to use the `cuda-memcheck` tool.  It's quite possible, for example, that a code that passes all CUDA runtime error checking will fail (and in fact have an actual coding defect) if run under `cuda-memcheck`.

There is no stated guarantee that the GPU will in normal operation detect invalid memory accesses.  It certainly has some capacity to do so, but it's not perfect.  I believe similar statements can be made about host code for the operating environments I am familiar with.